# How to connect an express multi page web app to its own API?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a backend express serve, node. It exposes all the necessary API I need. I have a react Single Page Application(SPA) admin web app that consumes the API. I need a a Multi Page Application (MPA) Content Management Site (CMS) for general internet user to get data from the API.

The problem is how to connect MPA to API. How should I get data from API at the backend and generate pages using the data in the same backend and without rewriting the API functions for MPA?

Comment: Is there any reason why the CMS app for general internet users cannot be implemented as another SPA?

Answer (score 0):

if you want multi page application of react you can [react router dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) its pretty good library, and for API calls you can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or native fetch function (you can also use ajax if you add jquery plugin in your react application, but while using axios or fetch you must set proxy to your api url in package json (reactjs) like this

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000" //add the port you use for your node app
```